# A data structure to quickly maximize a linear function on a fixed set of $k$-dimensional vectors

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Let $v_1,…,v_n$ be a finite list of vectors in $ℝ^k$ (with $k ≪ n$, in my case $k≈10$ and $n≈4~000$). I would like to know if I can precompute something so that given a linear form $f : ℝ^k→ℝ$, I can quickly get the $i$ maximizing $f(v_i)$. If $k=2$, I can do that with a convex envelope and a binary search. But even for $k=3$, I don't know how to organize the points of the convex hull to organize the search. Actually I'm not even sure it is feasible to compute the convex hull of my points with $k≈10$ since I see that it has complexity $O(n^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor})$.

I'm just looking for something faster than ranging over all the points for each new linear form that is given. In my case, I can probably discard a lot of points and reduce $n$ significantly but I'd like to know if there is a good worst case approach.

Comment: Why $O(n^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor})$ ? In $O(nk)$ time, you can evaluate all $O(n)$ linear forms and find the maximum per query. Do you know your queries in advance? How many queries are there? These would all be useful to know.

Comment: @AspiringMat This is the time complexity I found in [this paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/ConvexHullAlgorithm.pdf). I didn't look further into convex hulls in $k$ dimensions. And yes, $O(kn)$ per query is what I'm already doing, I was just saying that it's unlikely that precomputing the convex hull would actually help because it's apparently too slow (unlike if $k=2$). No, the queries are not known in advance, and I cannot give the number of queries. The context is an application that should react the the inputs of the user.

Comment: Closely related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/7719/5038.

Comment: Are you sure you actually need such a data structure? The naive approach requires a single matrix multiplication and finding a max coordinate of the resulting vector, which (with hardware acceleration) can probably be computed faster than what any fancy data structure can do (e.g., it's probably faster than the binary search for $k=2$).

Comment: @Dmitry The problem is that the queries are not known beforehand, I need to process them as the user gives them.

Comment: @D.W. Yes, this is exactly the same thing, thanks! edit: ah, I cannot mark as duplicate because it's not on the same website actually...

Comment: I don't see how it's the problem for what I suggest. Let $V$ be a $\mathbb R^{k \times n}$ matrix with columns $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, and let $q$ be the query ($f(v) = q^\top v$). Then you need to compute $q^\top V$, and find its maximum component.

Comment: @Dmitry Ok, I thought that you suggested to collect all the queries in a matrix $Q$ and compute $Q^{\top} V$. Sorry. You're right, probably it can be done faster than what I do by using numpy and hardware acceleration, I'll try that.